# What commands can I use to enable / disable Apache2 modules?

Tags: command-line, apache-httpd

What are the terminal commands used to enable and disable Apache2 modules?

**Update:** Since the commands appear to differ based on distribution, I have made this question a community wiki where hopefully each poster can indicate the commands they use along with the pertinent distributions in which they work.

Comment: The commands are different on different distros. Ubuntu/Debian is different from CentOS/RHEL, which is different then FreeBSD, etc. Please add a tag to indicate what distro you are using.

Comment: ... just change the config ...

Comment: If you're going to make the post CW, don't choose an answer.

Comment: I don't want to sound like I'm scolding you, it's just that CW is for questions that can have no best answer.  If you asked "What commands ... on Ubuntu ..." then feel free to choose the best.

Answer (score 4):

On debian / ubuntu you need to look at `a2enmod` and `a2dismod`. There are similar tools for toggling site configurations too (`a2ensite` and `a2dissite`).

Comment: I think a2enmod and a2dismod are on all platforms that carry apache.  I can comfirm openSUSE at least

Comment: @dec Gentoo doesn't have them, at least not automatically (there might be some package or useflag that includes them). [This](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout#Gentoo_.28Apache_httpd_2.2.29:) makes it sound like it's only Debian/Ubuntu and openSUSE

Comment: CentOS 5.5 doesn't have them either, which probably also means RHEL 5 doesn't. I don't have easy access to any other distros though.